# Issue with Batch Job completing abruptly

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

I am trying to process 1000+ records from Custom metadata(CMDT) via a batch job. This is how my business logic runs : In my start method, I query all the records from CMDT ,In my  execute method I start processing  records 1 by 1 from the scope, since I need to take the record and make a callout to external system for every record. So, since there are almost 1000 records, I am expecting to have 1000 'SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler' in logs for each record but what's weird is that every time there is almost 100 'SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler' only in the logs and when I monitor the job I see that job runs fine till the jobs processed number is 100 and suddenly the job completes and shows it has processed 1000 batches .
Any help would be highly appreciated. Is there any other way to solve the problem.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
return IRR_SEL_AutomatedMessagesSelector.newInstance().selectAutomatedMessages(); 
}
```

```
for ( SObject message : sObjScope ) {

// do some checks
List<MOD_PassengerInfo> PaxInfo = CON_AutomatedCommunication.getPassengerInfos(...);
MOD_AutomatedRequest automatedRequest = new MOD_AutomatedRequest();
        
          automatedRequest.passengerInfos = PaxInfo;

//makes the call out
CON_AutomatedCommunication.sendAutomatedCommunication(
          automatedRequest
        );

}
}
```

```
// execute
    BCH_SendAutomatedMessage processAutomated = new BCH_SendAutomatedMessage();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(processAutomated, 1);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include some minimal code detail, including how you call `Database.executeBatch`, the basics from `start` and in `execute`.

Comment: Included the code.